# Convergences of square of difference in probability implies convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> Consider real valued random variables $X,X_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $(X_n-X)^2\xrightarrow{P} 0$ then $X_n\xrightarrow{P} X$.

I tried using Chebyshevs inequality (which seems to be the usual "trick" for convergence in probability), but didn't get anywhere. I'm looking for hints to get me started.

Comment: If (xn-x)^2<eps^2 then |xn-x|<eps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|^2 \geq \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(|X_n-X| \geq \sqrt{\epsilon}).$$